# URL Rewrite and mod_jk

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, mod-jk

I want to redefine the base URL of a Tomcat webservice, mounted with JkMount. I tried the following:

```
JkMount /myapp/* ajp13_worker
RewriteRule ^/service/v1/(.*)$ /myapp/$1 [PT,QSA]
```

The original URLs work, for instance:

```
/myapp/
/myapp/brand
/myapp/classified?idBrand=0&priceMax=&page=1
```

The URL that I was trying to obtain were:

```
/service/v1/
/service/v1/brand
/service/v1/classified?idBrand=0&priceMax=&page=1
```

But they return 404 (from Apache, not from Tomcat). How to make it work?

**UPDATE**: I just forgot

```
RewriteEngine on
```

now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Which `mod_jk`'s version are you running?

Add the below line under the `JkMount` directive and try again:

```
JkOptions     +ForwardURIProxy
```

Comment: mod-jk 1.2.28-2, I read from the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html) that should be the default value. The default value is "ForwardURIProxy" since version 1.2.24. Anyway as I wrote in the update adding "RewriteEngine on" works.